# ROI Assertion failed (C++ and openCV)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a Student class and an imagehandler class (which as the opencv image handler)

Student object has a field:

```
imagehandler img;
```

and in the imagehandler class there is a function to copy image from one image to another into a certain location.

```
void imagehandler::copy_paste_image(imagehandler& dst, int xLoc, int yLoc){
 cv::Rect roi(xLoc, yLoc, m_image.size().width, m_image.size().height);
 cv::Mat imageROI (dst.m_image, roi);
 m_image.copyTo(imageROI);
}
```

and the imagehandler class has a Mat object m_image:

```
private:
 cv::Mat m_image;
```

Now in the main, I have declared a new image through the imagehandler specified constructor.

the constructor I use to make the image:

```
imagehandler::imagehandler(int width, int height)
: m_image(width, height, CV_8UC3){


}
```

in the main, I declare the image like this:

```
imagehandler CSImg((4*300), (320 * ceil((float)(numOfCSStudents/4))));
```

Trust me on this one: CSImg is way bigger than all of the images I want to input in it.

Now I want to copy a certain student's picture and input it into CS Img. That's what I do:

```
studentsVector.at(i)->getImg().copy_paste_image(CSImg, CSWidthCount*300, CSHeightCount*320);
```

And I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 303
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:303: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat
```

I've noticed that this happens in roi, I have no clue why. I -am- a total beginner at openCV and I am doing this for homework.

Thank you.
If you need any further info please ask.

Comment: this is indicative of a math/numbers error where you are exceeding the array bounds of something. check to make sure your ROI is smaller than your image, your copy stays within all image bounds, etc

Comment: they do... all sizes are correct.

Comment: what's the value of numOfCSStudents at the moment of error? Is numOfCSStudents an integer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about C++ API but this is what I did in C API;

```
CvRect ROI = cvRect(x, y, width, height);
cvSetImageROI(srcImg, ROI);
IplImage* cropImg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(srcImg), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);//this part very important
cvCopy(srcImg, cropImg);
cvResetImageROI(srcImg);
```